# Which wifi channel should I pick?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

My family is complaining that wifi connection is not stable, pages will periodically load slowly for a short period of time. I've checked around and the only thing I could think of is the wifi channels being over-crowded. This is what it looks like. I turned off my network so its not included in the graph.

[image: Neighbor wifi]

It looks kind of messy but could it be the cause of the slows? I read somewhere that its better to choose the same channel with others than to pick the one that is overlapping, but every channel is overlapping. Which channel would you choose if you were me?

Simply switching to 5Ghz isnt a solution for us since this is a 3 story concrete building and the rounter is placed on the 2nd floor. I checked and 5Ghz signal strength is pretty weak on the 1st and 3rd floor.

Comment: If you have lots of other Wifi's in your neighbourhood, then you have lots of other Wifi's in your neighbourhood. Next thing I'd try is to set up a WLAN router/repeater on the 1st and 3rd floor, if possible, with a wired connection to the 2nd floor. First try to carry the router to the 1st and 3rd floor, and check if this improves the connection. It could also be that the "loads slowly for a short period of time" is totally unrelated to Wifi reception, and e.g. a consequence of bufferbloat, either in your router, or in your ISP's system.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard this claim about using the same channel rather than overlapping. I don't put much stock in that.

It looks like Channel 6 or 12 is the best channel to use. However, your best bet is to overpower the other signals. In the location where you tested this only the signals on Channel 3 and 9 have much strength to them. You'd need to check if that's true in the other locations where client devices will be used. Spending some money on a really good access point with a high transmission power and multiple transmit and receive pairs will help... but you also need to make sure the client devices have the transmission power to reach the AP as well.

The ideal solution would be to install an access point on each floor using 5GHz and connect them via ethernet to the router. But, running such cables may not be a simple task given the building you describe.